# Getting the total of loop in php

Tags: php, loops

Can somebody help i'm trying get the total of loop.

Heres my code

```
echo '<form name="fproduct" action="product.php" method="post"> 
<br/><textarea name="item" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $j = 0;
    $arry=explode( "\\r\\n", $_POST['item'] );
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arry); $i++) {
        if((trim($arry[$i])) != null) {
            $j++;
        }
    }
    Print $j;
}
```

Whats wrong with this.

Comment: try `echo $j;` print work like `print($j);`

Comment: whats the context of this? your trying to count the number of items inside by newlines? but ignore empty spaces?

Comment: @CodeBaba ["print is not actually a real function (it is a language construct) so you are not required to use parentheses with its argument list."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

Comment: The total *what* of loop? What are you trying to count, what result are you seeing, what do you expect it to be instead, and what's your input data?

Comment: @CodeBaba yes i just want to count the line but ignore empty newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `\n` alone instead.

```
if(isset($_POST['item'])){
    $j = 0;
    $arry=explode( "\n", $_POST['item'] );
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arry); $i++) 
    {
        if((trim($arry[$i]))!= null){
            $j++;
        }
    }
    echo $j;
}
```

I suggest use `foreach`:

```
if(isset($_POST['item'])){
    $count = 0;
    $item = explode("\n", $_POST['item']);
    foreach($item as $line) {
        if(trim($line) != '') $count++;
    }
    echo $count;
}
```